# What does Upgrading Huntress Invisibility Do?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Most skills in Dungeon Defenders have a logical 'upgradeable' feature.  Damage, range, speed, etc are all numbers that can increase (or be decreased) logically.  But the Huntress has her Invisibility skill, which has no intuitively scalable difference.  It's on/off--visible or invisible.

What benefit does upgrading this skill give a Huntress?

Comment: I'd have to check again (Which is why its a comment not an answer) to be sure but I believe the amount of mana it uses to stay invisible is what is affected by the level increase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Invisibility):

> Putting points into this skill will decrease the amount of mana it takes to keep the skill on.
>
> If not leveled, you'll need 15 activation and 4 mana per second which will slowly increase the longer it is used.